# Forward packets from one port to another in same program

Tags: video-streaming, port, forwarding

I am writing a program to receive a video stream from VLC and forward it. I am using java. I created a port (1234)  and i am receiving packets in the port from vlc using UDP. I want to forward the packets to another port so that i can re-route it. but unfortunately i cant forward it .receiving part is working fine. How can i resolve it.  My code is given below

```
DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(1234);
          DatagramSocket sendSocket = new DatagramSocket(9999);

          InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
          System.out.println("Connected to server !");
          Thread.sleep(100);
          int i=0;
          byte[] recieveData = new byte[8196];
          byte[] sendData= new byte[8196];

          DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(recieveData,recieveData.length, IPAddress, 1234);
          while(true)
          {
              clientSocket.receive(dp);
              recieveData=dp.getData();
              sendData=dp.getData();
              System.out.println(recieveData.toString());
              System.err.println("chunk no: "+i+" , chunk length: "+ dp.getLength() + ".----> --> forwarding");
              i++;
              DatagramPacket sendPacket=new DatagramPacket(sendData, dp.getLength(), IPAddress, 9999);
              sendSocket.send(sendPacket);
          }
```